# Replacing NA's with LOCF using Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

My aim is to replace `NA`'s in a spark data frame using the *Last Observation Carried Forward* method. I wrote the following code and *works*. However, it seems to take longer than expected for a larger dataset.

It would be great if someone can recommend a better approach or improve the code.

**Example and Code with Sparklyr**

In the following example, `NA`'s are replaced after ordering them using the 
`time` and grouping them by `grp`.

```
df_with_nas <- data.frame(time = seq(as.Date('2001/01/01'), 
                                as.Date('2010/01/01'), length.out = 10),
                          grp = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)),
                          v1 = c(1, rep(NA, 3), 5, rep(NA, 5)),
                          v2 = c(NA, NA, 3, rep(NA, 4), 3, NA, NA))

tbl <- copy_to(sc, df_with_nas, overwrite = TRUE)

tbl %>%
  spark_apply(function(df) {
    library(dplyr)
    na_locf <- function(x) {
      v <- !is.na(x)
      c(NA, x[v])[cumsum(v) + 1]
    }
    df %>% arrange(time) %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate_at(vars(-v1, -grp), 
    funs(na_locf(.)))
  })

# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
#      time   grp    v1    v2
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 11323      1     1   NaN
#  2 11688.     1   NaN   NaN
#  3 12053.     1   NaN     3
#  4 12419.     1   NaN     3
#  5 12784.     1     5     3
#  6 13149.     2   NaN   NaN
#  7 13514.     2   NaN   NaN
#  8 13880.     2   NaN     3
#  9 14245.     2   NaN     3
# 10 14610      2   NaN     3
```

**data.table**

Following approach with `data.table` works quite fast for the data I have. I am expecting the size of the data to increase soon, and then I may have to rely on `sparklyr`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_with_nas)
df_with_nas <- df_with_nas[order(time)]
cols <- c("v1", "v2")

df_with_nas[, (cols) := zoo::na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE), 
                                 by = grp, .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this sort of loop, is quite slow...

df_with_nas = df_with_nas %>% mutate(row = 1:nrow(df_with_nas))

```
for(n in 1:50){
  df_with_nas = df_with_nas %>% 
    arrange(row) %>% 
    mutate_all(~if_else(is.na(.),lag(.,1),.))
}
```

run until no NA

then

```
collect(df_with_nas)
```

Will run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the spark_apply() function and run the `na.locf` function in each of your cluster nodes.

1. Install R runtimes on each of your cluster nodes.
2. Install the `zoo` R package on each nodes as well.
3. Run spark apply this way:

```
data_filled <- spark_apply(data_with_holes, function(df) zoo:na.locf(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite quickly using sql with the added benefit that you can easily apply LOCF on grouped basis.  The pattern you want to use is `LAST_VALUE(column, true) OVER (window)` - this searches over the window for the most recent column value which is not NA (passing "true" to `LAST_VALUE` sets `ignore NA = true`).  Since you want to look backwards from the current value the window should be

```
ORDER BY time
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND -1 FOLLOWING
```

Of course, if the first value in the group is NA it will remain NA.

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

test_table <- data.frame(
  v1 =   c(1, 2, NA, 3, NA, 5, NA, 6, NA),
  v2 =   c(1, 1,  1, 1,  1, 2,  2, 2,  2),
  time = c(1, 2,  3, 4,  5, 2,  1, 3,  4)
) %>%
  sdf_copy_to(sc, ., "test_table")

spark_session(sc) %>%
  sparklyr::invoke("sql", "SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(v1, true)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY v2
                         ORDER BY time
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND -1 FOLLOWING) 
                   AS last_non_na
                   FROM test_table") %>%
  sdf_register() %>%
  mutate(v1 = ifelse(is.na(v1), last_non_na, v1))
#> # Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
#>      v1    v2  time last_non_na
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1         NaN
#> 2     2     1     2           1
#> 3     2     1     3           2
#> 4     3     1     4           2
#> 5     3     1     5           3
#> 6   NaN     2     1         NaN
#> 7     5     2     2         NaN
#> 8     6     2     3           5
#> 9     6     2     4           6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>